# Condition state clear on componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, mount

I'm facing and issue here and I want a second opinion. When the first page of my app is rendered I want to clear my state for security reasons so in my layout class component I write:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.clearState();
}
```

The problem is that when I'm in the second page of my app and click backslash my state is clearing again. I want somehow to make a condition in my componentDidMount so as not to clear the state if I came from a page of my app. Is this possible? Do you have any other ideas of how to do this? Thanks a lot

Comment: is the state a redux state or a component state

Comment: You can try to pass param from child component like this:
this.props.cleatState(componentName)
And in your root component check it and make decision to clear state.

Answer (score 2):

If u don't use Redux u can try sessionStorage to store temporarily if the clearState() was fired.

```
//simple Example

componentDidMount() {
if (sessionStorage.getItem('clearState') === 0) {
 this.props.clearState();
 sessionStorage.setItem('clearState fired', 1)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to clear the state of your Component  inside componentWillUnmount() lifecycle method. It is the appropriate place to make cleaning.